# Microsoft Office programs (wine) can't save to cifs mount

Tags: wine, samba, cifs

I have mounted a folder from my NAS (Ubuntu Server 10.4, Samba) on my workstation (Ubuntu 11.4 CIFS) and everything works fine, except MS Office 2010 can't save to that folder. I see Word creates a temporary file and then it asks me for a new file name. Excel and Powerpoint do the same. There are not strange characters in the filename.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is only a partial answer, but I have found mounting the same shares over gvfs works. Using gigolo to automount makes this manageable.

I have experiment with just about every cifs setting, but can't find anything to help. I'd love to have a full answer to the same question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems there really isn't a way to mount cifs shares properly. I'm mounting the same directory via sshfs now and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make this work on my Readynas duo v2 with the following settings. My guess is that this will work on most systems with a little adaptation.

in /etc/frontview/smb.conf.CIFSFS I added:

```
unix extensions = 1
```

in /etc/frontview/Shares.conf I have the following (I don't know which bits, if any are important)

```
path = /c/leo_share
force create mode = 0666
create mask = 0666
force directory mode = 0777
directory mask = 0777
admin users = "admin","Administrator"
write list = "Leo","admin","Administrator"
valid users = "Leo","admin","Administrator","nobody"
vfs objects = recycle
recycle:versions = 1
recycle:repository = Recycle Bin
recycle:subdir_mode = 777
recycle:keeptree = 1
recycle:directory_mode = 777
```

I mount the share using:

```
//192.168.1.xx/leo_share <path> cifs credentials=<path>,file_mode=0700,dir_mode=0700,uid=1000,gid=100 0 0
```